# Mutate with dplyr using multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame (df) below and I want to add an additional column, `result`, using dplyr that will take on the value 1 if `z == "gone"` and where `x` is the maximum value for group `y`.

```
   y  x    z
1  a  3 gone
2  a  5 gone
3  a  8 gone
4  a  9 gone
5  a 10 gone
6  b  1     
7  b  2     
8  b  4     
9  b  6     
10 b  7
```

If I were to simply select the maximum for each group it would be:

```
df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  slice(which.max(x))
```

which will return:

```
   y  x  z
1  a 10  gone
2  b  7
```

This is not what I want. I need to take advantage of the max value of `x` for each group in `y` while checking to see if `z == "gone"`, and if `TRUE` 1 otherwise 0. This would look like:

```
   y  x    z result
1  a  3 gone      0
2  a  5 gone      0
3  a  8 gone      0
4  a  9 gone      0
5  a 10 gone      1
6  b  1           0
7  b  2           0
8  b  4           0
9  b  6           0
10 b  7           0
```

I'm assuming I would use a conditional statement within `mutate()` but I cannot seem to find an example. Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can use:

```
df %>% group_by(y) %>% mutate(result = +(x == max(x) & z == 'gone'))
```

The `+(..)` notation is shorthand for `as.integer` to coerce the logical output to 1's and 0's. Some don't like it so it's a matter of shorter code versus readability. Efficiency gains can be debated on the circumstance.

Also to appreciate what `data.table` and `dplyr` have done for data manipulation with R, let's do the same thing in the old-fashioned "split-apply-combine" way:

```
#split data.frame by group
split.df <- split(df, df$y)

#apply required function to each group
lst <- lapply(split.df, function(dfx) {
        dfx$result <- +(dfx$x == max(dfx$x) & dfx$z == "gone")
        dfx})

#combine result in new data.frame
newdf <- do.call(rbind, lst)
```

Comment: Alternate code-golf (arguably more readable): `(x == max(x))*(z == 'gone')`

Answer (score 6):

We can do this with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'y', we create the logical condition for maximum value of 'x' and the 'gone' element in 'z', coerce it to 'integer' (`as.integer`) and assign (`:=`) the output to the new column ('result').

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, result := as.integer(x==max(x) & z=='gone') , by = y]
df
#    y  x    z result
# 1: a  3 gone      0
# 2: a  5 gone      0
# 3: a  8 gone      0
# 4: a  9 gone      0
# 5: a 10 gone      1
# 6: b  1           0
# 7: b  2           0
# 8: b  4           0
# 9: b  6           0
#10: b  7           0
```

---

Or we can use `ave` from `base R`

```
df$result <- with(df, +(ave(x, y, FUN=max)==x & z=='gone' ))
```

Comment: thank you! this works as well `df %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  mutate(result = ifelse(x == max(x) & z == "gone", 1, 0))`

Comment: @RyanErwin That also works, I think the comment by PierreLafortune with `+(x==max(x) & z=='gone'` should be very fast for `dplyr`

Comment: thanks: I'm not familiar with `+( .... )`. Do you know where I can find documentation on this syntax?

Comment: nice solution with ave